# android : how to add rows(View) into existing custom listview adapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I need to alter my custom listview adapter, because i am listing values in adapter for pagination concepts. 
When the user clicks load-more button the list will add 10 more rows into listview and will show but the listview is default the first is shown but the listview focus should not change from lastviewed row?

```
PropertyListAdapter searchAdapter = new PropertyListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), searchResult, pagination);
searchListView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
searchListView.smoothScrollToPosition((pageId-1)*10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 my_array.addAll(other_array);
```

to add elements from a new array to your array. Then you can do:

```
 if(mylistAdapter ==null){
    mylistAdapter = new PropertyListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),myPropertyList);
    searchListView.setAdapter(mylistAdapter);
}else{
    mylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to update your ListView with the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

For adding custom rowview you can use baseadapter class add them through an row layout and set to adapter of listview

```
private class ViewHolder{
    public Button b;
}
Override getView and create something like this:

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHandler vh;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_layout, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        vh.b.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(i).intValue()));
        vh.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                if (listener != null){
                    listener.onListButonItemClicked(getItem(position).intValue());
                }
            }

        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: PropertyListAdapter is my custom adapter. i have already done this there. But what i want is to add new views to existing adapter. but i dont find any existing menthod like adapter.addView()...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the adapter type from BaseAdapter to ArrayAdapter. ArrayAdapter has function of add() and addAll() which can add rows dynamically to your listview as needed.